# Trying to find a percentage outcome of 3 dice rolls

Tags: .net, vb.net, random, probability, dice

Hey guys below I will paste my code for finding out the percentage chance of rolling the outcome (Please see my last outcome for a reminder)

Pretty much what I am trying to do is roll 3 dice store the total in 18 texboxes (One of each total 3,18) then work out what the percentage chance that the total was to roll it from the number of times rolled

(A fair warning my math is a little off but then mixing with code it makes it even worse plus I am only a first year programmer any help is required :( )

```
Imports System.Math

Public Class Form1
    Dim Numthrow As Integer
    Dim diceValue(18) As Integer
    Dim randomGen = New Random()
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim percenttotal(18) As Integer
    Dim cent As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Numthrow = TextBox1.Text
        For index = 1 To Numthrow
            Dim diceResult1 = randomGen.Next(1, 7)
            Dim diceResult2 = randomGen.Next(1, 7)
            Dim diceResult3 = randomGen.Next(1, 7)
            total = diceResult1 + diceResult2 + diceResult3
            diceValue(total) += 1

            cent = Numthrow * 100 / total
            percenttotal(cent) += 1
        Next

        Label21.Text = percenttotal(3)
        Label22.Text = percenttotal(4)
        Label23.Text = percenttotal(5)
        Label24.Text = percenttotal(6)
        Label25.Text = percenttotal(7)
        Label26.Text = percenttotal(8)
        Label27.Text = percenttotal(9)
        Label28.Text = percenttotal(10)
        Label29.Text = percenttotal(11)
        Label30.Text = percenttotal(12)
        Label31.Text = percenttotal(13)
        Label32.Text = percenttotal(14)
        Label33.Text = percenttotal(15)
        Label34.Text = percenttotal(16)
        Label35.Text = percenttotal(17)
        Label36.Text = percenttotal(18)

        TextBox2.Text = diceValue(3).ToString()
        TextBox3.Text = diceValue(4).ToString()
        TextBox4.Text = diceValue(5).ToString()
        TextBox5.Text = diceValue(6).ToString()
        TextBox6.Text = diceValue(7).ToString()
        TextBox7.Text = diceValue(8).ToString()
        TextBox8.Text = diceValue(9).ToString()
        TextBox9.Text = diceValue(10).ToString()
        TextBox10.Text = diceValue(11).ToString()
        TextBox11.Text = diceValue(12).ToString()
        TextBox12.Text = diceValue(13).ToString()
        TextBox13.Text = diceValue(14).ToString()
        TextBox14.Text = diceValue(15).ToString()
        TextBox15.Text = diceValue(16).ToString()
        TextBox16.Text = diceValue(17).ToString()
        TextBox17.Text = diceValue(18).ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        diceValue(18) = 0
        percenttotal(18) = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yeah so the total outcomes are 216 which I have changed recently to

Comment: cent = Numthrow / total * 100

Which is numthrow which can be 100 / total of the 3 dice which can out out between 3,18 then times 100 to get the prob

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off storing your rolled values in a List(of Integer). It will then be easier to keep track of the number and the sum.

If you are only interested in the probability after three rolls then you can just hard code the values - calculating this is not actually that easy to do as the equation looks like this:

[image]

So using the values [listed here](http://statistics.about.com/od/ProbHelpandTutorials/a/Probabilities-For-Rolling-Three-Dice.htm) :

```
Private _diceRollValues As New List(Of Integer)
Private _rnd As New Random

Private Sub RollClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim thisRoll As Integer = _rnd.Next(1, 7)
    _diceRollValues.Add(thisRoll)
    Debug.WriteLine("You just rolled: " + thisRoll.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine("The sum of your " + _diceRollValues.Count.ToString + " rolls is " + _diceRollValues.Sum().ToString)
    If _diceRollValues.Count = 3 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("The probability of this was: " + FindProbabilityFromThreeDice(_diceRollValues.Sum).ToString)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function FindProbabilityFromThreeDice(sum As Integer) As Double
    Select Case sum
        Case 3 : Return 1 / 216
        Case 4 : Return 3 / 216
        Case 5 : Return 6 / 216
        Case 6 : Return 10 / 216
        Case 7 : Return 15 / 216
        Case 8 : Return 21 / 216
        Case 9 : Return 25 / 216
        Case 10 : Return 27 / 216
        Case 11 : Return 27 / 216
        Case 12 : Return 25 / 216
        Case 13 : Return 21 / 216
        Case 14 : Return 15 / 216
        Case 15 : Return 10 / 216
        Case 16 : Return 6 / 216
        Case 17 : Return 3 / 216
        Case 18 : Return 1 / 216
        Case Else
            Throw New Exception("Invalid sum for three rolls of the dice")
    End Select
End Function
```